# literal double quotes around function parameter in bash scripting

Tags: shell

I want to create a shell script function that runs this:

`docker inspect 5914ba2819d6 | jq '.[0].NetworkSettings.Networks["foo"].IPAddress'`

I'm trying to get the function to run like:

`getcontainerip 5914ba2819d6 foo`

I've edited .bash_profile to have many permutations like this:

```
getcontainerip() {
   docker inspect "$1" | jq '.[0].NetworkSettings.Networks["$2"].IPAddress'
}
```

No matter what, the literal double quotes never get added surrounding the second parameter. The output will either be blank (because the double quotes aren't there), or a syntax error:

`jq: error: syntax error, unexpected '$' (Unix shell quoting issues?)`

How do I get the literal double quotes to surround the second parameter? Thanks.

Comment: With `jq` specifically you should use `--arg name value` or `--argjson name json` to pass variables to it. These options will handle escaping special characters correctly. If you inject `$2` directly into the script it's likely to fail if `$2` contains quotes, backslashes, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
getcontainerip() {
   docker inspect "$1" | jq '.[0].NetworkSettings.Networks["'$2'"].IPAddress'
}
```

The outer '' have the effect that $2 is not replaced with the second parameter but rather passed literally to jq. That's why you need to close the ''s temporarily to let the shell expand $2.

Comment: That works. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad to see that. You could mark the answer as a solution if you are satisfied.

Comment: While it works, the OP wanted for whatever reason to have literal **double** quotes around $2. I would therefore write `....Networks[\""$2"\"].IPAddress`

Comment: This is also acceptable. I believe the generated string would be identical.